# How to pull integer values from SQL Server database to C# Combobox?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, combobox

the example below presents what will happen after selecting random combobobx item. Sql query has run succesfully, however I get an error "the specified cast is not valid c#".

Combobox ***listaPrzedmiotow*** stores school subjects list in strings.
Combobox ***listaIndeksów*** is supposed to store a list of students indexes. In SQL Server database ***student indexes*** column accepts integer, so I do not know why .GetInt64(i) method is not valid for this.

```
private void listaPrzedmiotow_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(listaPrzedmiotow.SelectedItem.ToString());
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select studenci.NUMER_INDEKSU from dbo.oceny inner join studenci on studenci.numer_indeksu = oceny.numer_indeksu inner join dbo.przedmioty on przedmioty.przedmiot_id = oceny.przedmiot_id where przedmioty.NAZWA_PRZEDMIOTU = '" + listaPrzedmiotow.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", sqlConnection);
            SqlDataReader indexesList = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (indexesList.Read())
            {
                for (byte i = 0; i < indexesList.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    listaIndeksów.Items.Add(indexesList.GetInt64(i));
                }
            }
            indexesList.Close();
            indexesList.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is occurring because you are passing a byte at indexesList.GetInt64().

If you look at the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint64?view=netframework-4.8 it will show that

Try to change on the for loop the byte to int. If that not work, you can try Convert.ToInt32() and the value that you are catching on the loop